# How exactly would I make certain DataGrid columns readonly programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am having troubles making certain datagrid columns readonly.

**XML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="fieldsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></DataGrid>
```

**C# Code**

```
List<Field> fields = TestingClass.generateTestFields() // Generates the list
fieldsDataGrid.ItemSource = fields; 

// I tried both ways
FieldsDataGrid.Columns[0].isReadOnly = true;
FieldsDataGrid.Columns["Tokens"].isReadOnly = true; // Tokens is the column name
```

What I have attmpted
`FieldsDataGrid.Columns[0].isReadOnly = true;` In this case I ended up getting a index was out of range. It seems like when I debugged it Columns was empty? Why is it empty when I called `fieldsDataGrid.ItemSource = fields`

*If this is the incorrect way to implement this, please suggest a better option!*

Thank you for the help!

### edit

I have added in the XML `AutoGeneratedColumns = "true"` - I am still having the same error.

Comment: A WPF DataGrid won't automatically create columns based on the ItemsSource unless its `AutoGenerateColumns` property is True. As it is, it's expecting you to define the grid's columns, which you haven't.

Comment: `TestingClass.getTestFields()` - Please don't use java-like names in C#. They suck like nothing else I've ever seen. Create real properties and use the proper naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but getTestFields might sound misleading, it is not a getter, it is actual a function that generates a list. edit -  I changed the function name :)

Comment: @AustinTruong in that case name it properly: `GetTestFields` with an uppercase G.

Comment: @HighCore Thank you, I will make sure to try to get the naming conventions correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are autoGenerating columns, then use `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and set column's readonly property there. If you're adding columns manually, `IsReadOnly` property should be accessible directly through column name at the point of creation.